# Connect with database and fetch data to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have been wondering about this for a while. We are using Google Spreadsheets a lot with my colleagues and the thing is that we always have to write down data that we already have in our MySQL database.

I wonder if there is a possibility to connect your spreadsheet with MySQL server and fetch the data to specific rows via executable script or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [JDBC services of Google Apps Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#reading_from_a_database).

You will have to write a script that populates your spreadsheet with data from the JDBC service.

Not sure exactly what you want to do, but you could start with the example from the documentation:

```
function foo() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://<host>:3306/<instance>', 'user', 'password');
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.setMaxRows(100);
  var start = new Date();
  var rs = stmt.executeQuery('select * from person');

  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = doc.getRange('a1');
  var row = 0;
  while (rs.next()) {
    for (var col = 0; col < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); col++) {
      cell.offset(row, col).setValue(rs.getString(col + 1));
    }
    row++;
  }
  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
  var end = new Date();
  Logger.log('Time elapsed: ' + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}
```

Comment: How to do this with integrated authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Google AppScript JDBC](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#reading_from_a_database)

Here is some sample code that can get you started.

```
 // Replace the variables in this block with real values.
    var address = 'Your DB Address Here';
    var user = 'Enter USER';
    var userPwd = 'YOUR PASSWORD';
    var db = 'DATABASE NAME';

    var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address + '/' + db;

    // Read up to 1000 rows of data from the table and log them.
   function readFromTable() {
      var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

      var start = new Date();
      var stmt = conn.createStatement();
      // Read up to 1000 rows of data from the table and log them.
      // stmt.setMaxRows(1000);
      var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE');

      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var cell = sheet.getRange('A1');
      var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
      var row =0;

      while (results.next()) {
        var rowString = '';
        for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
          rowString += results.getString(col + 1) + '\t';
          cell.offset(row, col).setValue(results.getString(col +1 ));
        }
        row++
       Logger.log(rowString)
      }

      results.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();

      var end = new Date();
      Logger.log('Time elapsed: %sms', end - start);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[SeekWell](http://www.seekwell.io/?ref=so) allows you to connect to databases and write SQL queries directly in Sheets and MySQL is included in the free tier:

A few other features:

- Quickly view all tables and columns in a database and get summary
  stats on a column with one click
- Query from the sidebar, a large pop-out window, or from within a cell
- Results can be sent to a specific cell, scratch sheet or directly to a pivot table
- Your query history is saved and viewable if you need to re-execute an older
  query
- You can save a set of queries on a “Run Sheet” to update
  multiple reports at once

Disclaimer: I made this.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_name
into outfile '/somelocation/data.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Launch google spreadsheet. Open the data.csv file Your data is imported for use in Google.

Or do you want a real time connection?

Comment: Well real time connection would be better, but I am not sure if it is possible.

Comment: I have not done it with google docs, but I have done it with google calendar.  If you run a webserver with php it might be possible.  Download the API get the developer ID from google and a bunch of other stuff.